# Checking Gnome's version using Python

Tags: version, gnome

How do I use Python to check if the Gnome running is Gnome 2 or Gnome 3 ?

Comment: Please add a useful comment here instead of simply voting down. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both gnome 2 and gnome 3 use information from a certain file to display gnome version in System Info. The file in question is called *gnome-version.xml*

In gnome 3 it is part of the package *gnome-desktop* so it shouldn't be missing from any gnome 3 install regardless the distro. The difference is that in gnome 2 it's either installed in

*/usr/share/gnome-about/gnome-version.xml*

or missing, while in gnome 3 it's always located here:

*/usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml*

So I guess it's only a matter of checking for the right file in the right location.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for Gnome 3. I would take a look at it in Gnome 2 when I can find a distro still supporting it.

Comment: running "gnome-shell --version" show the version of the gnome installed. So I guess passing this command to python can still do it.

Comment: @Peter - I don't think so. That shows `gnome-shell` version (if any), not Gnome version (for that you need `gnome-desktop` version). See my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73225/22142)

Comment: Yeah, actually I missed to say shows "gnome shell" but forgot to type the "shell" part. My bad. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use python to run a command such as "gnome-about –gnome-version" in the operating system shell.

This bypasses distribution and indeed operating system package management nightmares as as long as gnome is installed in path it will respond correctly. No messy uses of apt/yum/pkg_*.

Look at python's Operating System module, specifically the os.system() command. http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system  . There are more elegant ways I'm sure, but this'll solve your issue.

Of-course this will only work if gnome is actually installed. I assumed it was given that you were asking what version it was. Lubuntu is a remix of standard ubuntu, and does not come with the full gnome desktop installed by default.

The following command will show installed packages that have gnome in the name.

```
dpkg -l | grep gnome
```

To find the exact name of the gnome-desktop package you'd do something like the following:

```
apt-cache search gnome desktop
```

And then the following to install a specific package.

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name_here>
```

Comment: I tried the "gnome-about --gnome-version" on Lubuntu (inside a VirtualBox) with kernel 3.0.0-16-generic and it tells me that 'gnome-about' is not available. "gnome-session" wouldn't work in Lubuntu either. I would like something that is out-of-the-box if possible.

Comment: "gnome-about" is not preinstalled inside Ubuntu 11.10 as well so that can be a problem.

Comment: See edit above. The package you're looking for is called "gnome-desktop" see link below for more details.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/oneiric/gnome-desktop